# SQL WHERE clause - multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I can't seem to get my syntax correct. The following query using pyodbc in Python v3.9 works.

```
SELECT name, state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE (name!= ('master')) AND (state_desc= 'offline')"
```

What I want to do in the WHERE condition is include the tempbd, model and msdb DBs along with the master DB. For example (but does not work):

```
SELECT name, state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE (name!= ('master', 'tempdb')) AND (state_desc= 'online')"
```

I've tried many different ways but just can't get it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `not in`

```sql
SELECT name, state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE (name not in ('master', 'tempdb')) AND (state_desc= 'online')"
```

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments by @DeepSpace, `not in` instead of `in`

Comment: `not in` more likely